# How is the loading script on this website implemented?

Tags: jquery

I found this wonderful website that have a loading bar on top of the page. The loading bar is like the browser's loading bar, but I find it very nifty and want to implement it as well in my pages.

[image]

http://www.cssjockey.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the site using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you can see that the author is using the jQuery JavaScript framework to implement the loading bar.

The relevant code, found in the `http://www.cssjockey.com/wp-content/themes/cj_pro/scripts/custom.js` script in the `<head>` section

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#loading").addClass("hidden");
});
 $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
 $(this).show();
 });
 $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 });
```

where `loading` is the id for the div containing the loading gif image

Answer (score 2):

He is using jQuery's [ajaxStart](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStart) and [ajaxStop](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStop)

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $(this).show(); 
});
$("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $(this).hide(); 
});
```

This basically allows him to show this loading image while any asynchronous call is being made.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** My answer is wrong, I answered with a different context in mind. However, I'm leaving it because the info could be useful for when you need to show a loading/progress bar.

He is using: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/.

However, he is not using its full capabilities (checkout the demo at the above URL).  The loading bar is just an animated gif file. I think you can get it at http://ajaxload.info.

Hope that helps. :)